# Exception starting filter struts2 Unable to load configuration. - bean

Tags: java, configuration, struts2

Hi I am new in Struts and trying to hello world in struts but I got error. I am trying to fixed it out but unable to do. The error message is

```
EVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/home/sudarshan/Desktop/RestFullTuts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/struts2starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.28.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:31:133
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:496)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5193)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/home/sudarshan/Desktop/RestFullTuts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/struts2starter/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.28.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:31:133
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:970)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:438)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:482)
    ... 14 more
```

**My `struts.xml` file is**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC  
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"  
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="getTutorial" class="com.sudarshan.action.TutorialAction">

            <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">error.jsp</result>
        </action>


    </package>
</struts>
```

**Web.xml is**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>struts2starter</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

so what is the solution for this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `struts2-portlet-plugin-2.3.28.jar` from the classpath. But for the solution to manage libraries you can use Maven.

See the tutorial that is built with Maven: [Create Struts 2 Web Application Using Maven To Manage Artifacts and To Build The Application](http://struts.apache.org/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-using-maven-to-manage-artifacts-and-to-build-the-application.html).

The minimal dependencies downloaded with

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.28</version>
</dependency>
```